# C# code to change browser download options

Tags: c#, firefox, browser

I am trying to do following with `c#`.

1) Open Firefox Browser-->Tools-->Options-->General Tab--->Downloads--->Always ask me where to save file.

I want to do this whole process in my application with `c#`. I want that when download window opens, the radio button in `"Always ask me where to save file"` option gets checked automatically.

I have tried from various links, but all is in vain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the full code, console application.
Summary: preferences file is located in application roaming folder, something like this on windows 7:

C:\Users\MYNAME\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\d9i9jniz.default\prefs.js

We alter this file so that it includes "user_pref("browser.download.useDownloadDir", false);"

Restart firefox, and done. Only run this application when firefox is not running.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (isFireFoxOpen())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Firefox is open, close it");
        }
        else
        {
            string pathOfPrefsFile = GetPathOfPrefsFile();

            updateSettingsFile(pathOfPrefsFile);
            Console.WriteLine("Done");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void updateSettingsFile(string pathOfPrefsFile)
    {
        string[] contentsOfFile = File.ReadAllLines(pathOfPrefsFile);
        // We are looking for "user_pref("browser.download.useDownloadDir", true);"
        // This needs to be set to:
        // "user_pref("browser.download.useDownloadDir", false);"
        List<String> outputLines = new List<string>();
        foreach (string line in contentsOfFile)
        {
            if (line.StartsWith("user_pref(\"browser.download.useDownloadDir\""))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Found it already in file, replacing");
            }
            else
            {
                outputLines.Add(line);
            }
        }

        // Finally add the value we want to the end
        outputLines.Add("user_pref(\"browser.download.useDownloadDir\", false);");
        // Rename the old file preferences for safety...
        File.Move(pathOfPrefsFile, Path.GetDirectoryName(pathOfPrefsFile) +  @"\" + Path.GetFileName(pathOfPrefsFile) + ".OLD." + Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
        // Write the new file.
        File.WriteAllLines(pathOfPrefsFile, outputLines.ToArray());
    }

    private static string GetPathOfPrefsFile()
    {
        // Get roaming folder, and get the profiles.ini
        string iniFilePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + @"\Mozilla\Firefox\profiles.ini";
        // Profiles.ini tells us what folder the preferences file is in.
        string contentsOfIni = File.ReadAllText(iniFilePath);

        int locOfPath = contentsOfIni.IndexOf("Path=Profiles");
        int endOfPath = contentsOfIni.IndexOf(".default", locOfPath);

        int startOfPath = locOfPath + "Path=Profiles".Length + 1;
        int countofCopy = ((endOfPath + ".default".Length) - startOfPath);
        string path = contentsOfIni.Substring(startOfPath, countofCopy);

        string toReturn = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + @"\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\" + path + @"\prefs.js";
        return toReturn;
    }

    public static bool isFireFoxOpen()
    {
        foreach (Process proc in Process.GetProcesses())
        {
            if (proc.ProcessName == "firefox")
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Could please try this out and tell me if you have any problems with it. If it works can you please mark this an answer?

Comment: Thanks alot..! this code really works for Firefox...!!! Is there any idea to do the same functionality in all other browsers..!!! and also any idea to do it while Firefox is in running mode..!

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried?

Firefox settings are stored [in your profile](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data), so I'd guess you can change the contents of the given file. Type `about:config` to find the setting you're looking for, I guess it's in the `browser.download` tree, alter it (after you made sure the browser isn't running) and you should be good to go.